# setting form input to a value in firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

Another Questions here,

I am trying to copy an input (or a value) from an input on my form to fire values,here is my code :

```
 <script>
    var dataBase = new Firebase ('https://yjyc-signup.firebaseio.com/Entries');
    var fName = document.getElementById('name');
    var eMail = document.getElementById('email');
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
    //var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber');
    var nameRef = dataBase.child('Name');
    var emailRef = dataBase.child('Email');
    //var phonenumberRef = dataBase.child('phone number');

    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

        dataBase.push({ 'name': 'hello', 'Email': 'Email', 'Phone number': 'phonenumber' });
        //nameRef.set(fName.value);
        //emailRef.set(eMail.value);
        //phonenumberRef.set(phoneNumber.value);
        swal("Thanks Alot!", "Thank you for signing up, a representative will be in touch with you shortly", "success")
    });

</script>
```

as you can see the 'name': is harcoded to hello , but I am looking to link it to the value of the name input at the form.

any suggestions?

Thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the dynamic value instead of hardcoded one you just need to use variables. Based on your code something like this should do the trick:

```
dataBase.push({ 'name': document.getElementById('name').value, 'Email': document.getElementById('email').value, 'Phone number': document.getElementById('phonenumber').value });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , by the way, can I for example just write fName.value?

Comment: Yes, if you have a reference of it somewhere above